# Angular-ui-grid pagination controls not being shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I´m using the following controller and HTML configuration to have a paginated ui-grid:

```
   app.controller('AdminProspectGridCtrl', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
    
        $scope.gridOptions = {
          data: 'myData',
          paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 100, 500],
          paginationPageSize: 25,
          enablePagination: true,
          enablePaginationControls: true,
          enableFiltering: true,
          enableColumnResizing: true,
          enableGridMenu: true,
          columnDefs: [
            { field: 'company'},
            { field: 'email'},
            { field: 'country'},
            { field: 'companySize'},
            { field: 'phone' },
            { field: 'dateCreated', cellFilter: 'date:"medium"' },
          ]
        };
    
        // Retrieve server data
        $http.get('/api/admin/test').then(function (response) {
                $scope.myData = response.data;
            }, 
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);  
        });
  });
```

The HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" />
<script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>

  <div class="tile-body" ng-controller="AdminProspectGridCtrl">

    <div id="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>

  </div>
```

The pagination controls simply does not appear on screen.

Comment: I also got the same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: Did you include the ui.grid.pagination module in your app.js file?

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue I resolved by adding a `'ui.grid.pagination'` dependency to the module

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.pagination'
]);
```

And my version is

```
"angular-ui-grid": "^4.8.0",
```

same for another issue here [angular-ui-grid pagination missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836964/angular-ui-grid-pagination-missing)

hope its resolved